# ARRAYFORMULA Using Row Above - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to create a column that contains a running decrementing tally, but is decremented by an amount from a different column on the same spreadsheet. Also, I would like to be able to add rows, without modifying this function. (i.e. such that this function will "Autofill" automatically when I insert new rows)

It seems like the ARRAYFORMULA will do this, but every time I've tried, I get a circular reference error. I have an example spreadsheet below with this error, can anyone correct my formula?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqcS_eDL_8umdEtLQ2s5Y1VYNk1wZUZrb25PajhfTkE&usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You get a circular reference because you have

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(C2:C - A3:A)
```

in column C. This is circular reference because column **C** references itself (**C2:C**) in the formula.

What you need is something like the following in column C

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(B2:C - A3:A)
```

Comment: The suggested solution being pasted in C3 leads to *Circular dependency detected*
Could you elaborate on it?